# How to activate Windows XP VM/mode in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

I don't see XP Mode or the XP VM in Windows 7 that I've heard some about.  Where is it?  Not in the Windows 7 Start menu...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [Windows XP Mode RC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) and just install it. Do notice that you need to have 64-bit Windows installed (Ultimate or Enterprise) and virtualization capable processor.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize it was a separate download and install.  BTW, it doesn't look like 64-bit Windows is required.  They have a 32-bit version to download.  I do have hardware virtualization support on my 32-bit machine.

Answer (score 1):

All is not lost for licensees of other Windows 7 versions. You can always use Windows XP as a guest OS in [**VirtualBox**](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and run applications in seamless mode.

[image]